# Is php checkdnsrr have equivalent for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, dns

Related to : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.checkdnsrr.php

I have old entries in my db to check as the code to verify email domain name is not yet set on my php, I wanna know if I can process with a mysql command the old entries I have in my db?

I didn't find any equivalents for that.

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is whether mysql can do a dns lookup with a built-in functionality?

Comment: @simbabque yes you're right

Comment: Is what you want to do a one-time job, or something you want to build into software to run regularly? What kind of operating system are we talking about?

Comment: @simbabque no it's a one time query I need

Comment: If you clarify the data you have and why this doesn't work from PHP I might be able to give you a Perl solution that will work if you're running Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not have that functionality accessible through SQL. There is no way to do what you want.

The server does have the ability to look up hostnames and put them in a [host cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache.html), but that is an internal functionality for resolving clients and storing information about connections.